# Edit mode when use Subdivision only show wireframe 2.8

Tags: edit-mode, eevee-render-engine, experimental-features

I want to ask about how to show the model when use Subdivision surface on blender 2.8.

Here is the difference when you use blender 2.79 vs 2.8 edit mode.

Blender 2.8 (11 August 2018 built)

[image]

Is it a bug or I missed something on blender 2.8?

Left is blender 2.79 and right blender 2.8.

Thank you

---

**Temporary Answer** 
From this forum (https://blenderartists.org/t/subdivision-preview-mode-missing/1114785/5) Ace_Dragon said that

> "The existing subsurf code is being ripped out and replaced with new code based on the OpenSubDiv library (which is becoming the industry-wide standard)."

Wait a while longer, it seems that for now this thing hasn't been included in blender 2.8.

---

**Update**

On the latest build, 12 Oct 2018, we can see the mesh when entering edit mode

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because about version 2.8 which is experimental unfinished version, and will change again much until stable release

Comment: @m.ardito as 2.8 is now in alpha 2.8 branch questions should not continue to be closed as off topic, the OP should rephrase the question to perhaps ask if the behavior is intended, or some feature rather than suggesting it is a bug.

Comment: @Timaroberts At this point 2.8 is still very hazy and undefined, there is no way to know for sure if these are bugs, limitations, or just unfinished features. Any solutions might just become invalid after release. Alpha level software is in no way ready for end users, and this alpha in particular was, as far as I know, used simply to mark the end of the code quest, not any particular maturity level or development milestone

Comment: I ask in this forum because I didn't want to bothering anyone in the developer forum. My question ask about is this bug or I missed something. If this is bug, anyone can report it to developer forum, so blender 2.8 is complete.

Comment: I edit flag and add experimental-features.

Comment: I think some blender users excited and use eevee in blender 2.8.

Comment: Don't bother developers with questions if you have any doubts use https://blenderartists.org or any other user community. The 2.8 bugtracker is closed for general bug reports unless it is a **reproducible** crash, that is why it is discouraged for end users.

Answer (score 0):

I Suggest You To Use Blender 2.79.Because 2.80 still got many bugs and 2.79 is a stable one . So I suggest You To Use The Stable One. HAPPY BLENDING

Comment: Got Questions Ask It .

Comment: Thank you for your response @IgamerAmrit, I add some information about newly blender 2.8 alpha.

Comment: Hey @FaresTP the reason I rejected your edit to this post, is because a change of that magnitude should be its own answer. I f you do want to add an answer, you can still get to your text [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/61553).